# Fetch multiple images with AWS Amplify React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am building a component that receives an array of objects, and within these objects I have some images.
I am not very experienced with Amplify, but what I understand is that you never receive the public URL itself, you receive a key and with this key you request the final URL. My problem is how to fetch different images and populate my html img tag.

The code I have so far:

```
const fetchOrganizations = async() => {
  const { data } = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listOrganizations))
  setOrgs(data.listOrganizations.items);
}
```

the output of this is an array of objects similar to this one

```
createdAt: "2020-09-12T10:44:11.003Z"
description: "b-1"
name: "b-1"
id: "cd032448-4498-4571-aa28-0e6379c48ae1"
logo: {
   bucket: "blablabla"
   key: "/public/us-east-1/blablabla.jpg"
   region: "us-east-1"
}
status: "CREATED"
```

and I am looping through this array to build my html.

```
{orgs.map(org => (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>{org.name}</li>
          <li>{org.logo && <img src={getOrgLogo(org.logo.key)} />}{org.name}</li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    ))}
```

and I have the function retrieving the images

```
const getOrgLogo = async key => {
   const image = await Storage.get(key)
   return image;
};
```

and the output I am having is

```
<img src="[object Promise]">
```

so, what is the right way to do something like this ?

Comment: Are you using AppSync to generate the GraphQL queries?

Comment: @yudhiesh yes. There's no problem with the query itself.